# How to use the Perl format function to print multiple columns

Tags: perl, formatting, output

I have a Perl hash like `%word`. The key is the word and the value is its count. Now I want to display `%word` like:

```
the  20       array  10       print     2
a    18       perl    8       function  1
of   12       code    5
```

I search and **Perl format** can solve this, and I learn this page  [perlform](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.10.1/pod/perlform.pod), but I still don't how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I knew about `format` and that it could be vary handy to generate nice forms... at the time we still had a world where all was monospaced...

So, I researched it a bit and found the following solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %word = (
     the      => 20,
     array    => 10,
     print    =>  2,
     a        => 18,
     perl     =>  8,
     function =>  1,
     of       => 12,
     code     =>  5,
);

my @word = %word; # turn the hash into a list

format =
@<<<<<<<<<<< @>>>>        @<<<<<<<<<<< @>>>>        @<<<<<<<<<<< @>>>>~~
shift @word, shift @word, shift @word, shift @word, shift @word, shift @word
.

write;
```

The nasty problem sits in the `~~` which makes the line repeating and that for each field in the format line you do need a corresponding scalar value... In order to get those scalar values, I shifted them off from the `@word` array.

There is a lot more to know about `format` and `write`.

Have fun!